# Equation involving prime sequence

Tags: prime-numbers

I tried to solve this equation:  $$3^{5+7+11+13+...+P(k-3)+P(k-2)}=P(k-1) \mod [ P(k) ],$$ where P(k) here is the $k^{th}$ odd prime number. The only solution I have found is $k=52$ or $P(k)=241$.  Could you find the next solutions for $k$?

Comment: what are odd primes?

Comment: Odd primes are 3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,....

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply. Sorry for asking, this is just for me to learn: Are there even primes too?

Comment: @Mehdi,no,even prime is excluded here.

Comment: @Mehdi Yes, 2 is even and prime!

Comment: @Fermat that is true! thanks, I just realized. never paid attention to this.